# Recurrence formula for the moments of a half-gaussian distribution (on R+)

Tags: normal-distribution, moments, integral

I am trying to compute an integral that looks like the moments of a Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, but the main difference is that we only integrate over R+ and not R. I believe we could call this the *moments of a Half-Gaussian distribution* :

$$I_m = \int_0^{\infty}x^m \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2\right)\mathrm{d}x, \quad m\in\mathbb{N}~.$$

I was wondering if there is a (recurrence) formula of $I_m$ for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

So far I found that:

- $m=0$: $I_0 = \dfrac{\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{{\mu}}{\sqrt{2}\,{\sigma}}\right)+1}{2}$
- $m=1$: $I_1 = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(1,\frac{{\mu}^2}{2{\sigma}^2}\right)\,{\sigma}+\left(2\sqrt{{\pi}}-\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{{\mu}^2}{2{\sigma}^2}\right)\right){\mu}}{2\sqrt{{\pi}}}$
- $m=2$: $I_2 = \dfrac{2^\frac{3}{2}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(1,\frac{{\mu}^2}{2{\sigma}^2}\right)\,{\mu}{\sigma}+\left(2\sqrt{{\pi}}- \operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{{\mu}^2}{2{\sigma}^2}\right) + \left(2\sqrt{{\pi}}-2\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{{\mu}^2}{2{\sigma}^2}\right)\right){\sigma}^2\right){\mu}^2}{2\sqrt{{\pi}}}$
- ...

with $\Gamma$ the *incomplete Gamma* function. This led me to the formula for $m>1$:
$$I_m = T_{m,\sigma} \mu^{m-1}\sigma + T_{m,\sigma^2} \mu^{m-2}\sigma^2 + \dots + T_{m,\sigma^{m-1}} \mu\sigma^{m-1} + T_{m,\sigma^m}\sigma^m = \sum_{n=1}^m T_{m,\sigma^n} \mu^{m-n}\sigma^n  $$

I managed to find a recurrence formula for $T_{m,\sigma^n}$ as a function of $m$ for $n=1,2,3,4$. However, I stopped there because it didn't seem to lead me to a general formula for any $n$. Also, the results I found are assuming that $\mu>0$, which is quite restrictive.

Given the nice form of the integral $I_m$ and its close relationship to the moments of a Gaussian, I was wondering if someone might know how to compute it and help me out...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your distribution is not really a [Half-Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) if $\mu \not=0$ but a [Truncated Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) at least if you rescale the density to integrate to $1$

Comment: The key is to use your Calculus skills to help the computer.  You can relate the formula for negative $\mu$ to that for $-\mu,$ so the sign of $\mu$ is no limitation.  $\sigma$ is a scale factor so you can set it to $1$ in your initial analysis to see how things work out. A single integration by parts produces a two-term recurrence for $I_m$ in terms of $I_{m-2}$ and $I_{m-1}.$

Answer (score 7):

Let $z = (x-\mu)/\sigma$ and write

$$I_m = \int_0^\infty x^m\, \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)\,\mathrm d x = \int_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty \left(\sigma z + \mu\right)^m e^{-z^2/2}\,\mathrm dz.$$

Fix $\mu$ and $\sigma.$  For $m \ge 1$ and $0\le d\lt 1$ define

$$J_d(m) = \int_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty (\sigma z + \mu)^{m-1+d}e^{-z^2/2}\,\mathrm dz.$$

An integration by parts gives

$$\begin{aligned}
J_d(m) &= \frac{(\sigma z+\mu)^{m+d}}{\sigma(m+d)}e^{-z^2/2}\bigg|_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty + \int_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty \frac{(\sigma z+\mu)^{m+d}}{\sigma(m+d)}\,ze^{-z^2/2}\,\mathrm dz\\
&= \frac{1}{\sigma(m+d)}\int_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma}\left(\sigma z+\mu - \mu\right)\left(\sigma z+\mu\right)^{m+d}e^{-z^2/2}\,\mathrm dz\\
&= \frac{1}{\sigma^2(m+d)}\left(J_d(m+2) - \mu J_d(m+1)\right),
\end{aligned}$$

which upon algebraic rearrangement yields a nice two-term recursion,

> $$J_d(m+2) = \sigma^2(m+d)J_d(m) + \mu J_d(m+1).$$

When (as in the question) $d=0,$ we may directly compute

$$I_0 = J_0(1) = \sqrt{2\pi}\,\Phi(\mu/\sigma); \quad I_1 = J_0(2) = \sqrt{2\pi}\left(\sigma e^{(\mu/\sigma)^2} + \mu \Phi(\mu/\sigma)\right).$$

to start the recursion.  Generally, we could compute $J_d(1)$ and $J_d(2)$ numerically and then use the recursion to find $J_d(m)$ with $O(m)$ additional effort.

---

For concreteness, here is `R` code for numerical evaluation of $I_m$ (for any non-negative real $m,$ not just natural numbers) as function `f` and to implement the recursion (function `g`).  The optional arguments `...` are passed to `integrate` to control its precision and accuracy.

```R
f <- Vectorize(function(m, mu = 0, sigma = 1, ...) {
  integrate(\(x) exp(m * log(x) - ((x - mu) / sigma)^2 / 2), 0, Inf, ...)$value
}, "m")

g <- Vectorize(function(m, mu = 0, sigma = 1, ...) {
  m.0 <- floor(m)
  d <- m - floor(m)
  y <- f(c(d, d + 1), mu, sigma, ...)
  if (m.0 >= 2) {
    for (j in seq(1, m.0 - 1))
      y[j + 2] = sigma^2 * (j + d) * y[j] + mu * y[j + 1]
  }
  head(y, m.0 + 1)
}, "m")
```

As a check and to illustrate, I used this recursion to evaluate $I_m$ over a grid for $\mu\in[-2,3],$ $\sigma\in[0.5,2],$ and $m=1,2,3,4.$  The values of `f` and `g` are identical to within floating point error.  Here are plots of `g`.

[image]